# Extend each std::tuple of an std::array with an extra element

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a type `facet` that basically represent a an array of tuple:

```
template <typename... Args>
struct facet {
    static constexpr std::size_t npoints = sizeof...(Args);
    using point_type = std::tuple<Args...>;
    using array_type = std::array<point_type, npoints>;

    facet(point_type, point_type); // imagine facet(point_type... )
};
```

The constructor is here simplified for 2 arguments, but imagine a constructor that can take n-arguments of type `point_type`.

I have another class that contains a vector of `facet`:

```
template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct X {

    using facet_type = facet<Args..., R>;

    using const_facet_type =
        std::pair<std::array<typename facet<Args...>::point_type,
                             facet<Args..., R>::npoints>, R>;

    // vector of facets
    std::vector<facet_type> facets_;

    X(std::vector<facet_type>);

    X(std::vector<const_facet_type> facets) {
        facets_.reserve(facets.size());
        add_facets(std::move(facets),
                   std::make_index_sequence<facet_type::npoints>{},
                   std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>{});
    }

    template <std::size_t... Is, std::size_t... Us>
    void add_facets(std::vector<const_facet_type> &&facets,
                    std::index_sequence<Is...>,
                    std::index_sequence<Us...>) {
        for (auto &&p: facets) {
            facets_.emplace_back(
                    std::make_tuple(
                        std::get<Us>(std::get<Is>(p.first))..., p.second)...);
        }
    }

};
```

The problem is in the second constructor - This constructor does not take a vector of facet, but instead a vector of pair array / `R`, where each point (tuple) inside the array contains N - 1 element (`sizeof... (Args)`).

My goal is to be able to construct an instance of `X` as follow:

```
X<double, double> x({
    {{0.0, 5.0}, 10.0},
    {{5.0, 8.0}, 12.0}
});

// which would be equivalent (using the first constructor)
X<double, double> x({
    {{0.0, 10.0}, {5.0, 10.0}},
    {{5.0, 12.0}, {8.0. 12.0}}
});
```

The problem lies in this line of code:

```
facets_.emplace_back(
    std::make_tuple(
        std::get<Us>(std::get<Is>(p.first))..., p.second)...);
//                                         ^^^ Us        ^^^ Is
```

Because I need to expand on both `Us` and `Is` ("cross"-expand them actually), which is not possible this way.

I could manually construct an array and then expand it, but I would like to know if there was a way to do it without having an extra array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, and if possible, you may group the sequence in only one, something like:

```
X(std::vector<const_facet_type> facets) {
    facets_.reserve(facets.size());
    add_facets(std::move(facets),
               std::make_index_sequence<facet_type::npoints * sizeof...(Args)>{});
}

template <std::size_t... Is>
void add_facets(std::vector<const_facet_type> &&facets,
                std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    constexpr auto size = sizeof...(Args);
    for (auto &&p: facets) {
        facets_.emplace_back(
                std::make_tuple(
                    std::get<Is % size>(std::get<Is / size>(p.first)),
                    p.second)...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Some kind of voodoo right there... :) You just inverted `Is / size` and `Is % size`, but otherwise this is great, thanks!